# animate div position on page scroll

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

I have a div that appears when a user scrolls down a page (you click it and it sends you back to the top of the page). Currently it just fades in and out, but I want it to slide in from the right hand side of the page.

Here is my current code:

Jquery:

```
<div class="toTop">
Back to the top
</div>
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()) {
        $('.toTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.toTop').fadeOut();
    }
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.toTop {
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgb(55,161,222);
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 0px;
    display: none;
    z-index:1000;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:600;
}
```

You can also see what I'm doing here:
http://www.samskirrow.com/client-hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `display:none`.

Set `right:-200px` and use `.animate({ right: 0px })` instead of `.fadeIn()` and `.animate({ right: -200px })` instead of `fadeOut()`.

Change your if statement to `if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100)`. This is because the `scrollTop()` function returns the current scroll position as a number of pixels from the top.

Comment: works perfectly when scrolling down, but doesn't when scrolling back up again. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Edited the answer for the new problem.

Comment: Thanks @Toast only final issue is that there is a random delay on the div moving back in (literally random - sometimes it's less than 5 seconds, sometimes it's more than 20 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

replace the `$('.toTop').fadeIn();` with `.animate({"right":"-50px"}, "slow");`

Comment: thanks @user1106295 how do I make it disappear again when I'm at the top??

Comment: did you add else { $('.toTop').animate({ right: -200px })} instead of the else....fadeout?